# group by variable and find cases for which some variables are all missing

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Sample data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 5 
k <- 10
my_labels <- LETTERS[1:5]

foobar <- data.frame(group = gl(n, k, labels = my_labels), x = runif(n*k), y=rnorm(n*k), z = rpois(n*k, 1), month_name = (rep(month.name[1:k], n)))
index  <- sample(1:50,10)
foobar[index, c("x", "y", "z")] <- NA
foobar[foobar$group %in% c("B","E"), c("x", "y", "z")] <- NA
```

I would like to find all and only those levels of `group`, for which all variables except `month_name` (and `group`, of course) are completely missing. In this case, these would be levels `B` and `E`.

The solution should use `dplyr` (if possible). If you need to select columns, don't  `select` just columns `x`, `y` and `z`, but rather deselect the columns you don't want to check, such as `group` and `month_name`. This is because in the real use case I have dozens of variables which must be checked for missingness, and just a few variables I don't want to check: of course in the example I used just three variables for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `filter_at` after grouping by 'group' to subset the rows

```
foobar %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter_at(vars(x, y, z) , all_vars(all(is.na(.))))
```

returns the rows where the 'group' is 'B' or 'E'

If the intention is to get the other 'group's, negate the expression in `filter`

```
foobar %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter_at(vars(x, y, z) , all_vars(!all(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: nice! Is `all_vars` a `dplyr` helper? However, using  `filter_at(vars(x, y, z),..` is a bit annoying. As I explained, in the real case the variables I need to check for `NA` are _much more_ than those I don't need to check, and they have weird names. I.e., it would become something like `filter_at(vars(x1, x2, x3, x3, A1, zc, Alpha_X, y1, OmegaVar, z1, Z2, z3, zmaybe, zalways, zpheraps, daylight_saving, foo, bar, barfoo, barbar, barbarbaberbar,...`. The variables I _don't_ need to check for `NA` are _much less_ and have simple names. Isn't there a way to negate `vars(..)`?

Comment: @DeltaIV  If you want to deselect, may be use `one_of`  you can check the syntax is `?select`

Comment: answer accepted. Any intuition on why this requires using `all_vars()`? I had a look at the help but it's a bit cryptic.

Comment: @DeltaIV  Thanks, I was away.  `all_vars` will look the condition to match for all the variables that are specified in the `vars` in the same row where as `any_vars` needs to have only a single variable meet the condition to filter that row.

Comment: @DeltaIV  I thought `-one_of` should work as it works in `select`, but may be it is a bug in `filter_at`.  You can use `foobar %>% group_by(group) %>% filter_at(vars(setdiff(names(.), "month_name")), all_vars(!all(is.na(.))))`